# How do I repeat the code form the top after a while loop?

Tags: python

I want this code to repeat from the top. Im trying to build a calculator app and when I say "Do you want to continue (y) or go back to home (n): " I want it so that if the user says "n" then it will start the code from the beggining. Here is the code I want to do this in.

```
# Importing stuff
import math
import random
import time
import numpy as np


def startup():
  global ask
  print("Welcome to this math python program")
  ask = input(
    "Do you wnat to solve 1, add, 2, subtract, 3, multiply, divide, or 5 other complex problems? (answer with 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5: "
  )


startup()
# Some stuff to make it look better
print("  ")
print("  ")


def add():
  print("Addition")
  num1 = int(input("First number: "))
  num2 = int(input("Second Number: "))
  num = num1 + num2
  print("The answer is " + str(num))


# Subtract


def subtract():
  print("Subtraction")
  num3 = int(input("First number: "))
  num4 = int(input("Second Number: "))
  num5 = num3 - num4
  print("The answer is " + str(num5))
  print("  ")


def multiply():
  print("Multiplication")
  num6 = int(input("First number: "))
  num7 = int(input("Second Number: "))
  num8 = num6 * num7
  print("The answer is " + str(num8))
  print("  ")


def divide():
  print("Division")
  num9 = int(input("First number: "))
  num10 = int(input("Second Number: "))
  num11 = num9 / num10
  print("The answer is " + str(num11))
  print("  ")


def squareRoot():
  print("Square Root")
  asksqrt = int(
    input("What number would you like to find the square root of: "))
  answer1 = math.sqrt(asksqrt)
  print("The square root of " + str(asksqrt) + " is: " + str(answer1))
  print("  ")


def cubeRoot():
  print("Cube root")
  num12 = int(input("What number do you want to find the cube root of: "))
  cube_root = np.cbrt(num12)
  print("Cube root of ", str(num12), " is ", str(cube_root))
  print("  ")


def exponent():
  print("Exponents")
  num13 = int(input("First you are going to tell me the number: "))
  num14 = int(input("Next you are going to tell me the exponent: "))
  num15 = num13**num14
  print(str(num13) + " to the power of " + str(num14) + " is " + str(num15))
  print("  ")


# While loops
while ask == "1":
  print("  ")
  add()
  ask4 = input("Do you want to continue (y) or go back to home (n): ")
  while ask4 == "y":
    add()

while ask == "2":
  print("  ")
  subtract()
  ask5 = input("Do you want to continue (y) or go back to home (n): ")
  while ask5 == "y":
    add()

while ask == "3":
  print("  ")
  multiply()
  ask6 = input("Do you want to continue? (y/n) ")
  while ask6 == "y":
    add()

while ask == "4":
  print("  ")
  divide()
  ask7 = input("Do you want to continue (y) or go back to home (n): ")
  while ask7 == "y":
    add()

while ask == "5":
  ask2 = input(
    "Do you want to do a 1, square root equation, 2, cube root equation, or 3 an exponent equation? (1, 2, 3): "
  )

  print("  ")
  while ask2 == "1":
    print("  ")
    squareRoot()
    ask8 = input("Do you want to continue (y) or go back to home (n): ")
    while ask8 == "y":
      add()

  while ask2 == "2":
    print("  ")
    cubeRoot()
    ask9 = input("Do you want to continue (y) or go back to home (n): ")
    while ask9 == "y":
      add()

  while ask2 == "3":
    print("  ")
    exponent()
    ask10 = input("Do you want to continue (y) or go back to home (n): ")
    while ask10 == "y":
      add()
```

I'm a begginer so I dont know a lot. If you could tell me what I can do better that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I see you selected the match/case answer. Just so you know, that example is a misuse of match/case, and is bad practice. Match/case is not an alternate syntax for if/elif. It's designed for pattern matching, which has nothing to do with your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to, you can see the code below:

```
while(input("want to continue (y/n)?") == 'y'):
operation = input("operation: ")
num_1 = float(input("first num: "))
num_2 = float(input("second num: "))
match operation:
    case "+":
        print(num_1 + num_2)
    case "-":
        print(num_1 - num_2)
    case "*":
        print(num_1 * num_2)
    case "/":
        print(num_1 / num_2)
    case other:
        pass
```

make sure you have the version 3.10 or later of python

Comment: Another user pointed this out to me, but the default case for match statements is actually `_`, not `other`. I made the same mistake.

Comment: you can write it in both ways

Comment: This is a misuse of match/case. Match/case is for pattern matching. You are teaching the OP bad practice.

Comment: i think that is not a bad practice... Maybe in python it seems to be only correctly used with pattern matching because match/case syntax is relatively new, but in C# we use switch/case code for a long time in cases like that

Comment: @FrankAyra - Good for C#. This is python and your answer is wrong. I'm not asking you, I'm telling you this is a misuse of match/case. Notice it is not "switch/case". It is "match/case" and it is used for pattern matching.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it's good to take a step back and think of what your main entrypoint, desired exit scenario and loop should look like. In pseudo-code, you can think of it like this:

```
1. Introduce program
2. Ask what type of calculation should be conducted
3. Do calculation
4. Ask if anything else should be done
5. Exit
```

At points 2 and 4, your choices are either `exit program` or `do a thing`. If you want to 'do a thing' over and over, you need a way of going from 3 back into 2, or 4 back into 3. However, steps 2 and 4 are basically the same, aren't they. So let's write a new main loop:

EDIT: [Decided to remove match/case example as it's an anti-pattern](https://mathspp.com/blog/pydonts/structural-pattern-matching-anti-patterns)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":                  # Defines the entrypoint for your code
    current_task = 'enter'
    while current_task != 'exit':
        current_task = ask_user_for_task()  # The user will input a string, equivalent to your startup()
        if current_task == 'add':           # If its 'add', run add()
            add()
        elif current_task == 'subtract':
            subtract()
        else:               
            current_task = 'exit'           # If its 'exit' or anything else not captured in a case, set current_task to 'exit'. This breaks the while loop
```

`ask_user_for_task()` will be an `input()` call where the user gives the name of the function they want to execute:

```
def ask_user_for_task():
    return input("Type in a calculation: 'add', 'subtract', ...")
```

This answer is not perfect - what if you don't want to exit if the user accidentally types in 'integrate'. What happens if the user types in "Add", not 'add'? But hopefully this gives you a starting point.

Comment: Something to note is that "match" and "case" keywords were added in python 3.10, if you are preparing this in an older version of python (or perhaps in a future version where it gets removed for any reason), you will need to use if/elif/else in place of match/case.

Comment: Good point - I debated whether or not to use `match` and `case` because they're newer keywords locked into 3.10 and above. For clarity, I'll add an if/elif/else method for other python versions

Comment: The only way this could look more like a chatGPT answer is if you didn't delete half of it and turn it into a gist.

Comment: Oh another thing to note for the `match` and `case`, doing `case other:` would actually have it compare to a variable named `other`. To set the default case the correct code would be `case _:`. Side note, as this is a "wildcard" as defined by the interpreter, not having that as the last case will also throw a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks Shorn - I was under the impression that `other` was the default case, but I misread that elsewhere. I'll change it now.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy - I need advice on something. This is the first time I've been accused of using ChatGTP to give an answer here. I don't need you to believe me either way, but I'm wondering what I should do in the future to not give this impression. I spent a fair bit of time thinking about how to explain to a beginner programmer who doesn't have a solid grasp of while loops how this problem can be solved. I gave inline comments to explain each step, broke the problem down into pseudo-code, introduced them to a return statement...all for someone to accuse me of using a bot. Dunno what to do here.

Comment: @PeptideWitch ~ don't make your answers look like you chopped up a chatGPT answer. It's mostly your naming conventions that give it away. Moving the comments to the side and reewording them was a nice touch.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy This hurts more than I care to admit. I'm not yet sure why...Why did you delete your answer by the way, I thought it was quite clever.

Comment: @PeptideWitch ~ I am regretful that you are hurt. I deleted my answer because I gave the OP a fully extensible solution, in short form, and they choose the worst possible answer just because it is short. They're going to figure that out eventually, and when they do, they're going to be right back where they started ... no solution.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy I feel you. I liked how you packed the `func` tuple with all the math operators and accessed them by index. Look, why don't you throw your answer back up and I'll give it an upvote. Part of the beauty of this site is that people months or years later can benefit from extra solutions, not just OP. I totally get its frustrating to see your work diminished and overlooked but that doesn't mean it isn't worthwhile. I picked up something from it, at least.

Comment: I wasn't aware that case/match was an anti-pattern and shouldn't be used like a `switch` - cf https://mathspp.com/blog/pydonts/structural-pattern-matching-anti-patterns. Removed case/match code in my answer.

Comment: @PeptideWitch ~ The reason I formulated my answer the way I did was to reduce branches (if/elif). It wasn't meant to be clever, it was meant to be more optimized. If I felt like playing with it more, I would remove all the branches. I'm one of those "no branches/never nest" people. Instead of processing some long list of conditions, my code goes directly to the thing we want.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do can be greatly simplified. The number you choose correlates to the index of the operation in `funcs`. Other than that, the program is so simple that each part is commented.

Using this method eliminates the need for excessive conditions. The only real condition is if it is a 2 argument operation or a 1 argument operation. This is also very easily extended with more operations.

```
import operator, math, numpy as np
from   os import system, name

#SETUP

#function to clear the console
clear   = lambda: system(('cls','clear')[name=='posix'])

"""
this is the index in `funcs` where we switch from 2 arg operations to 1 arg operations
more operations can be added to `funcs` 
simply changing this number accordingly will fix all conditions
"""
I = 6

"""
database of math operations - there is no "0" choice so we just put None in the 0 index.
this tuple should always be ordered as:
    2 argument operations, followed by
    1 argument operations, followed by
    exit
"""
funcs   = (None, operator.add, operator.sub, operator.mul, operator.truediv, operator.pow, math.sqrt, np.cbrt, exit)

#operation ranges
twoarg = range(1,I)
onearg = range(I,len(funcs))

#choice comparison
choices = [f'{i}' for i in range (1,len(funcs)+1)]

#this is the only other thing that needs to be adjusted if more operations are added
menu    = """
choose an operation:
    1:add
    2:subtract
    3:multiply
    4:divide
    5:exponent
    6:square root
    7:cube root
    8:quit
>> """

#IMPLEMENT

while 1:
    clear()
    print("Supa' Maffs")
    
    #keep asking the same question until a valid choice is picked
    while not (f := input(menu)) in choices: pass
    
    f = int(f)
    
    #vertical space
    print("")
    
    if   f in twoarg: x = (int(input("1st number: ")), int(input("2nd number: ")))
    elif f in onearg: x = (int(input("number: ")), )
    else            : funcs[f]() #exit
        
    #unpack args into operation and print results
    print(f'answer: {funcs[f](*x)}\n')
    input('Press enter to continue')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know it was that easy!